# How can I merge direct commits from a remote branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-merge, git-flow

I have two projects with similar code base. I work on new features on both repositories and I make some changes on both, that should not be shared to the other. I want to use branches in git, to make sure I can always merge the new features from one to another.

In *projectA* I create a feature branch from `projectA/master`, make few commits and merge them to `projectA/master`. In *projectB* I tried to merge `projectA/feature-branch` to `projectB/master`, but the *projectA* specific clutter would be merged as well.

It is possible to view all commits of the specific branch with

```
git show projectA/master..projectA/feature-branch
```

And I’d like to have something similar for merging

```
git merge --no-ff projectA/master..projectA/feature-branch
```

so that only the commits, directly committed to the `feature-branch` will be merged. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for cherry pick.

Git reference:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

And you can see this article:

https://ariejan.net/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/

I'd like to use a graphical tool like Git extensions for this, but it just up to you. I hope you find it useful (:

Comment: Thanks for your advise! After some testing I can confirm, that `cherry-pick` has a feature that helps me. It is possible to do something like I need with `git cherry-pick projectA/feature-branch projectA/master..projectA/feature-branch`, which is shown in an [example of the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_examples). Thanks again for pointing my to this :)